# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^n (n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}/n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^n \frac{(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2}$

Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^n \frac{(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2}$

Then $\log(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \log(\prod_{r=1}^n \frac{(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2})$

$\log(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \log( \frac{(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2})$

$\log(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n(\log( (n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}})-\log(n^2))$

$\log(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n( \frac{1}{n} \log( n^2(1+(\frac{r}{n})^2)^{})-\log(n^2))$

$\log(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n( \frac{1}{n}( 2\log(n)+\log(1+(\frac{r}{n})^2)^{})-\log(n^2))$

We see that 1 part becomes $\int_{0}^1 \log(1+x^2)dx$

How do I manipulate the remaining terms $\frac{1}{n}2log(n) - log(n^2)$?

Comment: For example, integrating by part:
$$\int_0^1\ln(1+x^2)dx=x\ln(1+x^2)\Big|_0^1-2\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx=\ln2-2\int_0^1dx+2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: No that I can do but what about the remaining terms $\frac{1}{n}2log(n) - log(n^2)$?

Comment: That part not being dependent on $r$, it gives after summing $2\log(n) - 2n\log(n) \to - \infty$

Comment: But just to be sure, was the $1/n^2$ supposed to be inside or outside the product? If it is really inside, then no problem with what's done here (beside writing $\lim$ when it hasn't been proven it exists, but maybe that's just a "me" issue...), but I have a suspicion it was meant to be outside?

Comment: In fact if you have summation like
$$\Big(\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2\ln n}{n}\Big)-\ln n^2=\frac{2\ln n}{n}n-\ln n^2=0$$ otherwise the limit is zero

Comment: If the $1/n^2$ was meant to be outside the product, then it becomes slightly more interesting and the log of the limit becomes what Svyatoslav first calculated above thanks to compensations from the terms in $\log(n^2)$, so I feel like the $1/n^2$ was indeed supposed to be outside.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I couldn't understand your calculation.How is $2ln(n).n/n - ln(n^2)=0?$. Also how are you getting this term? Is there a typo?

Comment: Please look at he comment by @Bruno B, which explains two possible options. If $1/n^2$ is inside the product (so, you have the expression $\frac{\prod\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n}(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^{2n}}$), then the limit is zero. More interesting is the case if $1/n^2$ is outside ($\frac{\prod\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n}(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2}$); then you have a more interesting case, and the formula I wrote is applicable.

Comment: @Svyatoslav how are you getting the formula?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that:

$$\prod\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n} \frac {(n^2+r^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2}\le \prod\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n}\frac {(n^2+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2}\le \frac {2n^2}{n^{2n}};$$

hence $L=0$.

Comment: Unless of course we're only supposed to divide the product by $n^2$ once rather than once per factor, in which case the limit is $2e^{\pi/2-2}$. (This is why I dislike notation of the form $\lim_{n\to c}\prod_{r\in S_n}f(n,\,r)/g(n)$.)

Comment: @J.G. Yes, Sir. Based on what the OP said and wrote, it seems $n^2$ was meant to be inside.

Comment: The $n^2$ is inside.

Comment: @Rajaei thanks for the answer but I just wanted to ask whether it was possible to continue it from the point I left it

Comment: @Antimony Sure. Yes, I think you can easy proceed from that point as it was discussed in the comment section above because $-\infty$ corresponds $0$.